# How can I use split with Beautifulsoup properly?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, split

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time
import re


r = requests.get("https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/")
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
qqrcoisa = soup.find("h1")
print(qqrcoisa)
lista = qqrcoisa.split(" ")
print(lista)
```

***Error: File "C:/Users/claud/Desktop/Nova pasta/scrapando.py", line 13, in 
lista = qqrcoisa.split("Documentation")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable***

Comment: you're getting that error because `qqrcoisa = soup.find("h1")` doesn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

Add the "text" function to the find function:

```
qqrcoisa = soup.find("h1").text
```

This will give you:

```
Beautiful Soup Documentation¶
```

And after splitting:

```
['Beautiful', 'Soup', 'Documentation¶']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the bs4 element to text by passing `text`

```
qqrcoisa = soup.find("h1").text
```

If you want to conserve the whole line in between `<h1>` and `</h1>` you can convert the bs4 element to a string

```
qqrcoisa = str(soup.find("h1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid throwing an error, you could run the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/")
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
qqrcoisa = soup.find("h1")
if qqrcoisa:
    print(f"Found this h1 element: {qqrcoisa.text}")
    lista = qqrcoisa.tetx.split(" ")
    print(f"Split h1 element: {lista}")
else:
    print("No h1 element found")
```

Comment: This will still throw an error if `soup.find("h1")` is None because you are trying to read the `text` attribute before checking if `soup.find("h1")` is None (so your `else` branch doesn't really match what you are printing : "No h1 element found").